# Accessing row cell count in Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I need to know how to get the count of cells in a Row object using OpenXML. Currently, I am using

```
row.Descendants<Cell>().Count<Cell>()
```

but this is not correct at all.  Any ideas what method/property gives me the count of cells?

Comment: I've just tested your code with a simple Excel document and it returns the correct cell count. Could you please tell us more about your problem. Does the row in question contain merged cells?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the count using one of the followings:

```
row.Descendants<Cell>().Count<Cell>() //The one you used

row.Elements<Cell>().Count<Cell>()

row.Count()
```

I tested all of them and they are working correctly. Keep in mind the following points while validating the correctness of the returned count:

- Hidden columns are included in the calculations

- Merged cells are counted separately. If your excel sheet contains **3 columns A, B & C, but A & B are merged**, then the count of the cells is **3 not 2**

You can extract a list of all the merged cells in a sheet using:

```
SpreadsheetDocument ExcelSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(ReportFile, true);
WorksheetPart ExcelWSP = GetWorksheetPartByName(ExcelSpreadSheet, TemplateEntity.ExcelSheetName);
MergeCells mergeList = ExcelWSP.Worksheet.Elements<MergeCells>().First();
```

The merge information is saved in the Reference property, and you can access it using the following:

```
((MergeCell)mergeList.ElementAt(i)).Reference
```